# Ubuntu: SSD TRIM is taking too long

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, trim

I posted this question before, but with no answer: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/400233/fstrim-is-taking-too-long).
I'm using ubuntu 13.10, I call `fstrim -v /` on boot `rc.local`.
Recently I realized that `fstrim` command is taking too long with above average CPU usage.

Is this normal ? It works eventually.

The only thing that changed, is this happened among Ubuntu failing to moung encrypted swap on startup. I fixed the swap problem, but fstrim still slow on startup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experienced similar behavior on my Debian Jessie only once, but this article (http://blog.neutrino.es/2013/howto-properly-activate-trim-for-your-ssd-on-linux-fstrim-lvm-and-dmcrypt/) helped me to understand the trimming function and how to adjust my own system.

I'm also using LVM and LUKS, so as the article recommend, I have configured trimming options for both of this services, removed the parameter from fstab and scheduled job of fstrim.

You may consider to remove fstrim from /etc/rc.local, do configuration changes and  schedule the job as suggested.

I have posted the same answer to your question on http://askubuntu.com in case somebody will find your question only there.